# Jsoup html parsing not taking TR, TD elements

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a flat file with HTML content. I'm trying to read text from it and parse the HTML content from it. I'm using jsoup to achieve this functionality.

My Sample string :

```
  <tr>
     <td><font color="#6C2DC7">Platform</td>
     <td><font color="RED" TITLE='n7k_reg_adxl07_2nd0'>aclxl</td>
     <td><font color="RED">0.0</td>
     <td><a href="http://wwwinearmstools.cisco.com/logs/viewfile.php?files[]=/auto/earmsdata/Earms/testlog-new/20079/88/89-1/report">200798889-1</a></td>
     <td><font color="GREEN">0</td>
     <td><font color="RED" title='Aborted: 0 Blocked: 0 Skipped: 0 Errored: 0'>1</td>
     <td><font color="#7D2252">&nbsp;</td>
     <td><font color="#827839">&nbsp;</td>
```

Unfortunately its not being able to parse this properly, without which I can't use any of the API methods to extract the content. Its parsing something like below :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<font color="#6C2DC7">Platform<font color="RED" title="n7k_xb45_F3100G_2nd0">qos_100G_FLK_xb_sup3<font color="RED">73.01<a href="http://wwwin-earmstools.cisco.com/logs/viewfile.php?files[]=/auto/earmsdata/Earms/testlog-new/20076/79/43-1/report">200767943-1</a><font color="GREEN">238<font color="RED" title="Aborted: 0 Blocked: 0 Skipped: 0 Errored: 0">88<font color="#7D2252">&nbsp;<font color="#827839">&nbsp;</font></font></font></font></font></font></font>
</body>
</html>
```

Whats wrong with this. How can I make it work to get the TR,TD elements and proceed to use the jsoup methods to extract my required content.

**Sample Code :**

```
String html = "<html><body><tr><td><font color=\"#6C2DC7\">Platform</td><td><font color=\"RED\" TITLE='n7k_xb45_F3100G_2nd0'>qos_100G_FLK_xb_sup3</td><td><font color=\"RED\">73.01</td><td><a href=\"http://wwwin-earmstools.cisco.com/logs/viewfile.php?files[]=/auto/earmsdata/Earms/testlog-new/20076/79/43-1/report\">200767943-1</a></td><td><font color=\"GREEN\">238</td><td><font color=\"RED\" title='Aborted: 0 Blocked: 0 Skipped: 0 Errored: 0'>88</td><td><font color=\"#7D2252\">&nbsp;</td><td><font color=\"#827839\">&nbsp;</td></tr></body></html>";
String charSet = "ISO-8859-1";
Document innerHtml = Jsoup.parse(html,charSet);
```

Comment: @Reimeus Please check it now. My bad. I forgot to add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TR` and `TD` are HTML table tags but your input HTML does contain any `<table>` tags so the tags themselves are ignored by `JSoup`, so just add these tags

```
String html = "<html><body><table>...</table></body></html>";
```

If you can't add the tags then it's invalid as HTML so needs to be parsed as `XML`

Comment: Thanks!! It works fine now. Such a basic thing I missed. The files are feeded by external service. I'll add these tags while parsing.